# How to keep the order when resolving promises (Promise.allSettled)?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

This code performs a GET request for each case id in `cases`. It then validates if each case is full or has an error.

```
let cases = [ /* array of case objects having the property CaseId */ ];
let promises = [];

// fetch all cases first
cases.forEach(c => promises.push(CaseSource.get(c.CaseId)));

// validate each case
Promise.allSettled(promises).then((results) => {
  results.forEach((promise) => {
    if (promise.status === "fulfilled") {
      let fetchedCase = promise.value;
      let caseSize = fetchedCase.Evidences.length;
      if (caseSize + 1 > MAX_CASE_SIZE) {
        fullCases.push(fetchedCase.Title);
      } else {
        validCases.push(fetchedCase);
      }
    } else {
      let error = promise.reason;
      this.loadCaseError(ApiException.parse<IExceptionModel>(error), /* need to use c.CaseId here... */);
    }
  }); this.loadAllCases(fullCases, validCases);
});
```

I would like to be able to have the case id of a case which has an error. However, it is not a property that is in promise.reason and I cannot add it. The ids are in the original `cases` array.

I thought about keeping track of the index of the promises, however, I don't think the promises will resolve in the `promises` array in the same order as the GET requests are performed (not guaranteed since asynchronous).

Is there a way I can keep the order?

Comment: Map the request ID to an object as a key that sets the value of success/failure.

Comment: If you add `i` in `results.forEach((promise, i) => {`, then you can just do `cases[i]` to get the corresponding case, inside your forEach. The results are kept in order by `Promise.allSettled`, no matter the order of resolves/rejects

Comment: could use map() instead of forEach() to get back an array of promises in the same order as fed.

Comment: @blex So the order of `promises` will be the same as `cases`? How are the order kept by `allSettled` if the get requests are done in the `forEach` beforehand, and only the resulting array is put into the `allSettled`? Is `forEach` the one keeping the order?

Comment: @dandavis Do you mean that `map` keeps the order of asynchronous calls but not `forEach`?

Comment: i must have misread the code; how is an array of strings having a `.CaseId` property on each string? If they are objects, you could tack on the promise, or tack on the id to the promise (they are objects) inside the first forEach.

Comment: @FryingPan `Promise.allSettled` resolves to an Array of results which maintains the order that you provided to it. Here is a simple example showing that: https://jsfiddle.net/op2zn6x4/1/ So if you know the index of the result, you know the index of the case which corresponds to it

Comment: @dandavis Yes they are objects! sorry, I edited the post. What do you mean by "tack on the promise"?

Comment: @blex Thanks! So the array will compose of the promises with "pending" status in correct order. I see it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The results of `Promise.all/allSettled` are strictly in the insertion order, therefore you should be able to simply access the source by its index:

```
Promise.allSettled(promises).then((results) => {
  results.forEach((result, INDEX) => {
    if (result.status === "fulfilled") {
      ....
    } else {
      let error = promise.reason;
      whatever(error, cases[INDEX]);
    }
```

For a more general case, where inputs are not available after promises are settled or their order is not known, you can use `all` with a wrapper as a more flexible alternative to `allSettled`:

```
Promise.all(
    INPUTS.map(input =>
        FUNC(input)
            .then(result  => ({status: 'fulfilled', result, input}))
            .catch(reason => ({status: 'rejected', reason, input}))
    ))
```

so that arbitrary payload can be added to the `result` object.